# How do I fix my Tetris blocks from spinning?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const blockSize = 20;
const numRows = 20;
const numCols = 10;
const screen = new Array(numRows).fill(0).map(() => new Array(numCols).fill(0));
let gameStarted = false; // New variable to track game start
let paused = false; // Variable to track whether the game is paused
const tetrominoes = [{
    shape: [
      [1, 1, 1, 1]
    ],
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    shape: [
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1]
    ],
    color: "orange"
  },
  {
    shape: [
      [1, 1, 1],
      [0, 0, 1]
    ],
    color: "yellow"
  },
  {
    shape: [
      [1, 1, 1],
      [0, 1]
    ],
    color: "green"
  },
  {
    shape: [
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1]
    ],
    color: "blue"
  },
  {
    shape: [
      [1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 1]
    ],
    color: "indigo"
  },
  {
    shape: [
      [0, 1, 1],
      [1, 1]
    ],
    color: "purple"
  },
];
let tetromino = getRandomTetromino();

function drawBlock(x, y, color) {
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(x * blockSize, y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.strokeRect(x * blockSize, y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // Draw filled blocks on the screen
  for (let y = 0; y < numRows; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < numCols; x++) {
      if (screen[y][x] !== 0) {
        drawBlock(x, y, "gray");
      }
    }
  }
  if (!gameStarted) {
    // Draw initial screen message
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.font = "14px Arial"; // Adjusted font size
    const message = paused ? "Game Paused - Press Space to Resume" : "Press Enter to start the game";
    const textWidth = context.measureText(message).width;
    context.fillText(message, (canvas.width - textWidth) / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  } else {
    // Draw Tetromino
    tetromino.shape.forEach((row, y) => {
      row.forEach((value, x) => {
        if (value !== 0) {
          drawBlock(tetromino.x + x, tetromino.y + y, tetromino.color);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // Draw pause/resume message
  if (paused && gameStarted) {
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.font = "10px Arial"; // Adjusted font size
    const pauseMessage = "Game Paused - Press Space to Resume";
    const pauseTextWidth = context.measureText(pauseMessage).width;
    context.fillText(pauseMessage, (canvas.width - pauseTextWidth) / 2, canvas.height - 10);
  }
}

function moveDown() {
  tetromino.y++;
  if (checkCollision()) {
    tetromino.y--;
    placeTetromino();
    clearLines();
    if (isGameOver()) {
      endGame();
    } else {
      spawnTetromino();
    }
  }
}

function moveLeft() {
  tetromino.x--;
  if (checkCollision()) {
    tetromino.x++;
  }
}

function moveRight() {
  tetromino.x++;
  if (checkCollision()) {
    tetromino.x--;
  }
}

function rotate() {
  const originalShape = tetromino.shape;
  tetromino.shape = rotateMatrix(tetromino.shape);
  if (checkCollision()) {
    tetromino.shape = originalShape;
  }
}

function getRandomTetromino() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tetrominoes.length);
  return {
    shape: tetrominoes[randomIndex].shape,
    color: tetrominoes[randomIndex].color,
    x: Math.floor((numCols - tetrominoes[randomIndex].shape[0].length) / 2),
    y: 0,
  };
}

function rotateMatrix(matrix) {
  const rows = matrix.length;
  const cols = matrix[0].length;
  const result = new Array(cols).fill(0).map(() => new Array(rows).fill(0));

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      result[j][rows - 1 - i] = matrix[i][j];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function checkCollision() {
  for (let y = 0; y < tetromino.shape.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < tetromino.shape[y].length; x++) {
      if (
        tetromino.shape[y][x] !== 0 &&
        (screen[tetromino.y + y] && screen[tetromino.y + y][tetromino.x + x]) !== 0
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function placeTetromino() {
  tetromino.shape.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((value, x) => {
      if (value !== 0) {
        screen[tetromino.y + y][tetromino.x + x] = 1;
      }
    });
  });
}

function clearLines() {
  for (let y = numRows - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
    if (screen[y].every((value) => value !== 0)) {
      // Clear the line
      screen.splice(y, 1);
      screen.unshift(new Array(numCols).fill(0));
    }
  }
}

function spawnTetromino() {
  tetromino = getRandomTetromino();
}

function isGameOver() {
  // Check if the top row has any filled blocks
  return screen[0].some((value) => value !== 0);
}

function endGame() {
  // Perform actions when the game is over
  gameStarted = false;
  paused = false;
  alert("Game Over! Press Enter to restart.");
  resetGame();
}

function resetGame() {
  // Reset the game state
  screen.forEach((row) => row.fill(0));
}

function togglePause() {
  paused = !paused;
}

function update() {
  if (gameStarted && !paused) {
    moveDown();
  }
  draw();
}

// Handle keyboard input
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  if (!gameStarted && event.code === "Enter") {
    // Start or resume the game on pressing Enter
    gameStarted = true;
    paused = false; // Ensure the game is not paused when starting
  } else if (gameStarted) {
    // Continue handling other keys during the game
    switch (event.code) {
      case "ArrowLeft":
        moveLeft();
        break;
      case "ArrowRight":
        moveRight();
        break;
      case "ArrowDown":
        moveDown();
        break;
      case "ArrowUp":
        rotate();
        break;
      case "Space":
        togglePause(); // Pause or resume the game on pressing Space
        break;
    }
  }
});
// Game loop
setInterval(update, 500);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="400"></canvas>
```

This source code is a Tetris program I wrote using html, css, and
javascript.
The Tetris block I wanted to work is like this photo.
[image]
However, when the program was actually run, the shape of some Tetris blocks changed strangely as they were rotated.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[[image]]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiSwk.png)
[image]
Even though I wrote the program to rotate the blocks clockwise in 90 degree increments, some of the blocks rotate strangely.
[image: Correct rotation of tetris blocks]
Please let us know the problem and modify the source code so that the Tetris blocks rotate without changing their shape strangely.

I continued to modify functions related to Tetris rotation.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.